# Relative height of float element in inline parent box without position:absolute

Tags: css, css-float, height, inline

I am trying to add a link arrow to my inline parent box using float and clear. The size of the parent box is variable and is therefore adjusting with text size / zoom.
For a better understanding here the basic structure of the Code:

```css
*.wrap_content_pic_left{
/*Size */
  width: 98%;
 /*Position */
  display: inline-block;
    background: red;


}
*.wrap_content_pic_left a#link  {
float: right;
 clear: right;
 width: 3%;
 height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap_content_pic_left">
  <a href ="" id="link">& raquo </a>
  <h3> Some Text </h3>
  <h3> Some more text</h3>
</div>
```

Is there a way to define the size of the link box to the height of the parent box in a relative way (not using px or em)?